# how to check if any one element of a variable length String array is present in another variable length string array

Tags: dataweave, mule4

```
inputArray = ["cat", "bat", "mat"]  
configuredArray = ["dog", "elephant", "fox", "cat"]
```

`inputArray` and `configuredArray` are variable length String arrays.

If any one element of the `inputArray` is present in the `configuredArray` I would like to set a bloolean flag.
How do I write it in `Dataweave 2.0`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You could leverage the `filter` and `contains` functions and do something like this. Also leaves you with a reusable functin.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun any(left: Array, right: Array) =
    sizeOf(left filter (right contains $)) > 0

---
["cat", "bat", "mat"] any ["dog", "elephant", "fox", "cat"]
```

Comment: extra point for using a binary function as an operator.

Comment: Great and concise solution

Comment: Keep in mind that this method has no short-circuit logic, so for especially large payloads this isn't going to be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var arr1 = ["cat", "bat", "mat"]
var arr2 = ["dog", "elephant", "fox", "cat"]

---
sizeOf(arr1 reduce (item, acc = []) -> if (arr2 contains item) acc + item else acc) >0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform -- operation between the arrays and based on difference in size, we can easily evaluate it.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inputArray = ["cat", "bat", "mat"]  
var configuredArray = ["dog", "elephant", "fox", "cat"]
---
{
   match : (sizeOf(inputArray -- configuredArray) < sizeOf(inputArray))
}
```